# clion build configuration. How to build multiple targets?

Tags: clion

Can any1 tell me how to configure cLion Run/Debug configuration so it builds both release and debug, and any other config I would like to? I'm trying to output my .lib d.lib so they are ready for usage... I tried adding "before launch" and add debug/release there but seem to not do anything...

A side question, how can 1 project execute 2nd project builds so that I can always make sure my libs are up to date?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clion > editConfiguration > +(add) > Compound > add ur desired outs there.

Hit build and it will make it happen.

Comment: Have you any idea why build button is inactive for me? I have to run it, and killing every process afterwards.

Comment: @ArmanBabaei usually it means ur cmake failed. Rear error log in messages/build/etc tabs

Comment: This seems to be designed not to build but for run: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-debug-configuration-compound-run-configuration.html

Comment: Incorrect answer. There is no "Build" to hit, only "Run." It can kind of work, but you get two pop-ups for each step without a target executable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple workaround for this in CMakeLists.txt add:

```
add_custom_target(MyGroupOfTargets)
add_dependencies(MyGroupOfTargets
    MyApp1
    MyApp2 # any cmake valid target you want
    FancyApp
    MyLib
    )
```

Now in Clion you can build target `MyGroupOfTargets`